# How to import dynamic json file directly to dynamo DB?

Tags: java, jackson, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have a json file upto maximum nesting level of 5 and the json file is dynamic means don't know what key-value pair present inside it but the each item inside json file is compliance with Dynamo DB table and has one attribute(per item) of same name as hash key.

Now how can I directly import this json data file to DynamoDB?

is there any command like mongoimport in dynamo to directly load json file?
or any technique using Jackson or other java library to load dynamic jsonto dynamo?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a script that build the DynamoDB Json and put it into you db through aws-sdk.
if you have more than one Item, so use the DynamoDB BatchWrite item, you can see the doc for DynamoDB BatchWrite Item

Here is a script i developed with javascript. my script is reading a CSV file and building a Json for each row, and add it to a global Json (BatchWrite DynamoDB Json), so it upload it to the table :

```
var fs = require('fs');

var parse = require('csv-parse');
require('should');

let AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const {
    Observable
} = require('rxjs');
const {
    map,
    retryWhen,
    flatMap,
    takeWhile,
    filter,
    switchMap
} = require('rxjs/operators');

output = [];
next = true;

tmp = [];

let params = {
    RequestItems: {
        'YOU DYNAMODB TABLE NAME': []
    }
}

fs.readFile("./data/produits.csv", function(err, data) {

    //console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
    parse(data.toString('utf8'), {
        comment: '#',
        delimiter: ';',
        relax_column_count: true,
        relax: true

    }, function(err, output) {

        this.output = output;
        let j = 0;


        doAdd(j, 24)




    })
})


function doAdd(j, max) {
    add(j, max).subscribe(tmp => {
        j = j + 25;
        let params = {
            RequestItems: {
                'YOU DYNAMODB TABLE NAME': []
            }
        }

        console.log(tmp.length)


        if (tmp.length > 0) {
            params.RequestItems['YOU DYNAMODB TABLE NAME'] = tmp;
            create(params).subscribe(data => {
                if (j < this.output.length && this.output.length - j > 25) {
                    doAdd(j, 24);
                } else if (j < this.output.length && this.output.length - j < 25) {
                    doAdd(j, this.output.length - j - 1)
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            })
        }

    })

}

function add(j, max) {


    return new Observable(Observer => {
        console.log("-----------> " + j);


        let tmp = []

        for (i = j; i <= j + max; i++) {
            console.log(this.output[i][0], " ", this.output[i].length)


            listTag = getDynamoList(this.output[i][41], "S")
            listAccessory = getDynamoList(this.output[i][42], "S")
            listCategories = getDynamoList(this.output[i][43], "N")

            //console.log(this.output[i])


            if (this.output[i]) {
                let Items = {
                    'PutRequest': {
                        'Item': {
                            '_id': {
                                S: this.output[i][0]
                            },
                            'name': {
                                S: this.output[i][3]
                            },
                            'description': {
                                S: this.output[i][1]
                            },
                            'description_short': {
                                S: this.output[i][2]
                            },
                            'link_rewrite': {
                                S: this.output[i][4]
                            },
                            'meta_description': {
                                S: this.output[i][5]
                            },
                            'meta_keywords': {
                                S: this.output[i][6]
                            },
                            'meta_title': {
                                S: this.output[i][7]
                            },
                            'id_supplier': {
                                S: this.output[i][8]
                            },
                            'id_manufacturer': {
                                S: this.output[i][9]
                            },
                            'id_category_default': {
                                N: this.output[i][10]
                            },
                            'id_tax_rules_group': {
                                S: this.output[i][11]
                            },
                            'online_only': {
                                N: this.output[i][12]
                            },
                            'ean13': {
                                S: this.output[i][13]
                            },
                            'upc': {
                                S: this.output[i][14]
                            },
                            'quantity': {
                                N: this.output[i][15]
                            },
                            'minimal_quantity': {
                                N: this.output[i][16]
                            },
                            'price': {
                                N: parseFloat(this.output[i][17]).toString()
                            },
                            'wholesale_price': {
                                N: parseFloat(this.output[i][18]).toString()
                            },
                            'unity': {
                                S: this.output[i][19]
                            },
                            'unit_price_ratio': {
                                N: parseFloat(this.output[i][20]).toString()
                            },
                            'additional_shipping_cost': {
                                N: parseFloat(this.output[i][21]).toString()
                            },
                            'reference': {
                                S: this.output[i][22]
                            },
                            'supplier_reference': {
                                S: this.output[i][23]
                            },
                            'location': {
                                S: this.output[i][24]
                            },
                            'width': {
                                N: parseFloat(this.output[i][25]).toString()
                            },
                            'height': {
                                N: parseFloat(this.output[i][26]).toString()
                            },
                            'depth': {
                                N: parseFloat(this.output[i][27]).toString()
                            },
                            'weight': {
                                N: parseFloat(this.output[i][28]).toString()
                            },
                            'out_of_stock': {
                                N: this.output[i][29]
                            },
                            'quantity_discount': {
                                N: this.output[i][30]
                            },
                            'customizable': {
                                S: this.output[i][31]
                            },
                            'active': {
                                S: this.output[i][32]
                            },
                            'available_for_order': {
                                S: this.output[i][33]
                            },
                            'available_date': {
                                N: new Date(this.output[i][34]).getTime().toString()
                            },
                            'condition': {
                                S: this.output[i][35]
                            },
                            'show_price': {
                                S: this.output[i][36]
                            },
                            'visibility': {
                                S: this.output[i][37]
                            },
                            'date_add': {
                                N: new Date(this.output[i][38]).getTime().toString()
                            },
                            'date_upd': {
                                N: new Date(this.output[i][39]).getTime().toString()
                            },
                            'image': {
                                S: this.output[i][40]
                            },
                            'tags': {
                                L: listTag
                            },
                            'accessory': {
                                L: listAccessory
                            },
                            'other_categories': {
                                L: listCategories
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                tmp.push(Items)

                for (let i in Items.PutRequest.Item) {


                    for (let j in Items.PutRequest.Item[i]) {



                        if (!Items.PutRequest.Item[i][j]) {
                            delete(Items.PutRequest.Item[i])
                        }
                    }
                }
                params.RequestItems['YOU DYNAMODB TABLE NAME'] = tmp;
            }



        }
        Observer.next(tmp)

    })






}


function getDynamoList(array, type) {
    let tmp = [];
    if (array) {
        let tmparray = array.split(",")
        for (let item of tmparray) {
            let empty = {};
            empty[type] = item;

            tmp.push(empty)

        }

        return tmp
    }
    return ''
}


function uuid() {
    let uuid = "",
        i, random;
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        random = Math.random() * 16 | 0;

        if (i == 8 || i == 12 || i == 16 || i == 20) {
            uuid += "-"
        }
        uuid += (i == 12 ? 4 : (i == 16 ? (random & 3 | 8) : random)).toString(16);
    }
    return uuid;
}




function create(params) {

    return new Observable.create(Observer => {
        var creds = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'YOUR IDENTITY POOL ID'
        })


        AWS.config.update({
            region: 'eu-central-1',
            credentials: creds,
            apiVersions: {
                dynamodb: '2012-08-10'
            }
        });

        var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
            region: 'eu-west-3'
        });


        return dynamodb.batchWriteItem(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                return Observer.error(err);;
            } else {
                return Observer.next(data);
            }
        });

    })

}
```